# Comparing Query Results to Current User

Tags: php, mysql

Everytime a user logs in for the first time, I save some information about them. If the user already has entry and the entry is out-dated then it should be updated. My problem is trying to compare the user to the database to see if they already have an entry. I successfully log the user's details but it does this everytime the user logs in. Below you can find my code.

```
$conn = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'db');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Error; Contact Support!");
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from users where steamid=? ");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $steamprofile['steamid']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($res);
$duplicate = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if ($duplicate == 0) {
    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("REPLACE INTO `users` SET `steamid` = ?,`realname` = ?,`username` = ?");
    $stmt1->bind_param('sss', $steamprofile['steamid'], $steamprofile['realname'], $steamprofile['personaname']);
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->store_result();
    $stmt1->bind_result($res1);
    if ($res1 === TRUE) {
        echo "";
    }
    $stmt1->close();
    $stmt->close();
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid all this complicated logic by simply using INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE:

```
$conn = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'db');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Error; Contact Support!");
}

$query = "INSERT INTO `users` SET `steamid` = ?,`realname` = ?,`username` = ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE realname=? , username=?"
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt1->bind_param('sssss', $steamprofile['steamid'], 
        $steamprofile['realname'], $steamprofile['personaname'], 
        $steamprofile['realname'], $steamprofile['personaname']);
$stmt1->execute();
$stmt1->store_result();
$stmt1->bind_result($res1);
if ($res1 === TRUE) {
    echo "";
}
$stmt1->close();
mysqli_close($conn);
```

You are completely eliminating the need to run a query first up to find out if the record already exists.

Also note that the query can also be written as

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` SET `steamid` = ?,`realname` = ?,`username` = ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE realname=VALUES(realname) , username=VALUES(username)"
```

In that case you would not need to bind the username and realname params twice.

Note that this is also superior to REPLACE INTO because replace results in the entire row being replaced instead of just one column being updated. Thus REPLACE INTO may result in the index having to be recalculated.

Answer (score 0):

Could be you have a typo

```
duplicate = mysqli_num_rows($res);
```

instead of

```
$duplicate = mysqli_num_rows($res);
```

(but this shouldn't raise an error?)

You use

```
("REPLACE INTO `users` SET `steamid` = ?,`realname` = ?,`username` = ?")
```

I think you should use INSERT  for new user and update for existing users

```
("INSERT INTO `users` (`steamid`,`realname`, `username`) values( ?, ?,?")
```

and

```
("UPDATE `users` SET `steamid` = ?,`realname` = ?,`username` = ?
  WHERE `your_user_id`  = ? ")
```

Comment: The `$duplicate`, believe it or not, doesn't raise any errors. I haven't the slightest clue on how to see if the user already has a DB entry, this was my sad attempt at it though. @scaisEdge

Comment: steam id is the user_id ? .. be sure you have a proper value in $steamprofile['steamid'] ..eg : using var_dump($steamprofile['steamid']); and then check for $duplicate eg: var_dump($duplicate );